# How to set HTTP Strict Transport Security in Laravel and how can it vary by computer/browser?

Tags: laravel, https, http-status-code-401

A client of us gets a 401 error on certain api endpoints, that our web app calls through jQuery with $.ajax

It's only on "his computer" and we can't reproduce it here. :/

While checking i noticed 'HTTP Strict Transport Security' is 'enabled', while when we check it we have 'HTTP Strict Transport Security' as 'disabled' for exact same call. It thought it was server side.

[image]

1/ How is this possible?

2/ How can you set the HTTP Strict Transport Security through Laravel?

Comment: check this https://www.yellowduck.be/posts/automatically-adding-the-hsts-header-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

In the end the issue was a "stupid" www.domain vs .domain call.

The comment from Wildfire lead to seeing the issue. Thanks!